# How to detect finger touched point on the circle drawn on canvas in android?

Tags: android, canvas

I am working on an Android application in that I have drawn a circle and also moving along with finger touched point. But my problem is when i touch any where in the screen its starts from there, I want to move when i  touch within the circle only. Please help me.
Here is my code,

```
 public class Circle extends View {

    int xTouch = 0;
    int yTouch = 0;
    int radius = 100;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public Circle(Context context, int x, int y) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        xTouch = x;
        yTouch = y;
        Log.v("" + xTouch, "" + yTouch);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(xTouch, yTouch, radius, p);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int actionIndex = event.getActionIndex();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            xTouch = (int) event.getX(0);
            yTouch = (int) event.getY(0);

            invalidate();

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            xTouch = (int) event.getX(actionIndex);
            yTouch = (int) event.getY(actionIndex);
            invalidate();

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record the coordinate of last touch.

When there a new ACTION_DOWN,

compare the touch coordinate with the last,

see whether their distance is smaller the radius.

If so, move the circle to new coordinate

Answer (score 0):

**Action_Down** -- for the first pointer(finger) that touches the screen.This starts the gesture.

**Action_Pointer_Down** -- for the extra pointer(second finger) that enters the screen beyond the first.

**Action_Move** -- A change has happened during a press gesture

**Action_Pointer_Up** -- sent when a non primary pointer goes up.

**Action_Up** -- sent when the last pointer leaves the screen

now you can code according to above actions.